# JQuery, How to diasable dropdownlists value when other dropdownlist value that selected

Tags: jquery

I wrote a script that can add dropdownlist with button, and every dropdownlists can't select the same value from database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("select").change(function() {   
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
  }); 
});
```

But still it is not working.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue here, in stacksnippet or https://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
```

..should be:

```
$("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $(this).val() + "']").prop('disabled', true);
```